# Probability one number is the divisor of the other, choosing from a list of numbers in the range (1,20)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I found this question and it seems very interesting.

Given the set $\{1,2,3., ... , 20\}$. Every item has a probability $p_x$ to be chosen, where $x$ is the $x'th$ number. We choose two numbers independently. Show that the probability of one being a divisor of the other is at least $1/10$.

My attempt:

Let W = "One number divides the other"
, $C_x$ = "x number was chosen"

Then, $P(W) = P(C_1)P(C_2+C_3+...+C_{20}) + P(C_2)P(C_4+C_6+...+C_{20})+...$

$= p_1(p_2+p_3+..+p_{20}) + p_2(p_4+p_6+...+p_{20})+...\geq p_1(p_2+p_3+...+p_{20}) = p_1 (1-p_1)$

Which does not lead to something useful.

I also read about probability of coprimality as in [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality), which seemed relevant, but it only applies on uniform probabilities.

Any thoughts on this problem? Any material to study relevant theory or examples?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Partition $\{1,2,3,\ldots, 20\}$ into $\{1,2,4,8,16\}$, $\{3,6,12\}$, $\{5,10,20\}$, $\{7,14\}$, $\{9,18\}$, $\{11\}$, $\{13\}$, $\{15\}$, $\{17\}$ and $\{19\}$, and consider the probabilities that both are drawn from one of these subsets
- If $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} x_i = 1$, then what is the minimum possible value of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} x_i^2$ ?